# Automatically export a change log from a shared Excel workbook upon un-sharing it

Tags: excel, vba, shared, changelog

I have a shared workbook on my organization's network share drive which is edited by a few dozen individuals. About once a week, I need to take it out of "Shared" mode (let's call this "un-sharing") to do run some advanced operations on the data input by these editors, and make changes that require me to unprotect the worksheet/workbook. Also, I occasionally have to perform maintenance on the VBA code in the workbook, which also requires me to un-share the workbook.

The problem is that every time I un-share, it erases the internal track-changes history. I would like to automate exporting this history to an external change-log file, otherwise saving the change history every time requires cumbersome and time-consuming manual effort.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around the internet trying to find a way to access Excel's internal change history and coming up with nothing, I settled on this solution that utilizes Excel's Highlight Changes option to temporarily create a "History" sheet, then append the changes listed on that sheet to a csv file. I also tried to make it relatively reusable and modular:

```
'My function that disables workbook sharing
Function UnshareWkbk(wkbk as Workbook) as Boolean
    on Error goto errUnshare
    'If Sharing is already disabled, return TRUE and exit
    If Not (wkbk.MultiUserEditing) Then
        UnshareWkbk = True
        Exit Function
    Else
        'Sharing is enabled, unshare the workbook here
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        'If we are about to Unshare, we need to export the change log first
        Call ExportChangeLog(ThisWorkbook, "1/1/1900")

        'Go ahead and Unshare the workbook, it's safe to erase the change history
        wkbk.ExclusiveAccess
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    'Make sure it worked and return TRUE
    If Not (ThisWorkbook.MultiUserEditing) Then UnshareWkbk = True
    Exit Function

errUnshare:
    '[add your own error handling here as applicable]
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function

'Export changes from workbook from selected date to present
Sub ExportChangeLog(wkbk As Workbook, fromDate As Date)
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range
    Dim logFile As Integer, logPath As String
    Dim isNewFile As Boolean, fileIsOpen As Boolean
    Dim errStr As String

    On Error GoTo changeLogErr

    With wkbk
        'If the workbook is open in read only mode then we don't need to save
        'the changelog since the change history won't be erased
        If wkbk.ReadOnly Then GoTo endExportLog

        'Create History sheet for changelog using Excel's Hightlight Changes procedure
        .HighlightChangesOptions When:=Format(fromDate, "m/d/yyyy")
        .ListChangesOnNewSheet = True
        .HighlightChangesOnScreen = False

        'If a History sheet is not created that means there have been no changes since 
        'the chosen date, so go ahead and skip this procedure.
        On Error GoTo endExportLog

        With .Sheets("History")
            On Error GoTo changeLogErr
            .Activate

            'Set rng to just the actual changes in the change log, ignoring the extra data
            'output by Excel in the History worksheet and the headers
            'Note: you may care about this additional data, I do not
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = .UsedRange.Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3).Offset(1)
            Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count - 3).Offset(0, 1)
            On Error GoTo changeLogErr

            'If no rng is set, the History sheet was created but there were no
            'changes... this shouldn't happen, but just in case I've added this
            'code which will skip this procedure
            If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo endExportLog
        End With

        'Move view away from the History sheet
        .Sheets(1).Activate
    End With

    'Initialize the log file
    logPath = wkbk.Path & "\changelog.csv"
    logFile = FreeFile  'Next available file number

    'If the file doesn't currently exist, set isNewFile to TRUE
    isNewFile = Dir(logPath) = ""

    Open logPath For Append As logFile

    'If we've made it here then the log file is ready to be written to
    fileIsOpen = True

    'Print table headers if the file doesn't yet exist
    If isNewFile Then
        'If you changed the rng selection above, you may need to update the 
        'table headers here:
        Print #logFile, "DATE,TIME,WHO,CHANGE,SHEET,RANGE,NEW VALUE,OLD VALUE"
    End If

    'For each row in the change log, write to the CSV
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        Print #logFile, RangeToCSV(rw)
    Next rw

    'UNTESTED, but you should be able to replace the above for loop with this*
    'Print #logFile, RangeToCSV(rng)

endExportLog:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Save and close changelog
    If fileIsOpen Then Close #logFile
    Set rng = Nothing: Set rw = Nothing
    Exit Sub

changeLogErr:
    errStr = "ERROR #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    msgbox errStr
    On Error Resume Next
    'If an error happened after preparing the log file, we can also log the error there
    if fileIsOpen then Print #logFile, "ERROR," & Format(Now(), "YYYY.MM.DD_hhmm") & "," & errStr
    Resume endExportLog
End Sub

'Convert a given range (1D or 2D) to CSV and return as a string
Function RangeToCSV(ByRef rng As Range) As String
    Dim arr() As Variant, strArr() As String
    Dim outputStr As String, i As Long, j As Long

    'If only one cell in rng, return just that cell's value
    If rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        RangeToCSV = rng.Value2
        GoTo endRngToCSV
    End If

    'Store values of range to array
    arr() = rng.Value2
    ReDim strArr(0 To UBound(arr, 2) - 1)

    'More than 1 row of data, add vbnewline between csv rows
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        For j = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                strArr(i - 1) = Replace(arr(j, i), ",", ".")
            Next i
            outputStr = IIf(j = 1, Join(strArr, ","), outputStr & vbNewLine & Join(strArr, ","))
        Next j
    Else 
        'Only one row of csv data
        For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            strArr(i - 1) = Replace(arr(1, i), ",", ".")
        Next i
        outputStr = Join(strArr, ",")
    End If

    'Return CSV output
    RangeToCSV = outputStr

endRngToCSV:
    'Clean up
    On Error Resume Next
    Erase arr: Erase strArr: Set rng = Nothing: outputStr = ""
End Function
```

*I originally wrote the RangeToCSV function to only work with single rows of data, hence the for each rw loop in the ExportChangeLog procedure

Comment: *I'd love to see your improvements, additions, changes, comments, etc!* that is more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)